# Finding the limit of a quotient of sums (of functions)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

I encountered the following basic problem in my research.

Given $\alpha_{i} \geq \beta_{i} > 0$, $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} r_{i} (t) = 0$, where $r_{i}(t)$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$. Given an integer number $n$, Find the limit:
$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}r_{i}(t)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_{i}r_{i}(t)}$.

If the limit doesn't always exist, are there conditions I can place on the $r_i$ so that there will be a finite limit?

Comment: Well, you know $\lim \frac{\sum \alpha_i r_i}{\sum \beta_i r_i} \geq \frac{\sum \alpha_i r_i}{\sum \alpha_i r_i} = 1$, so the limit isn't 0.

Comment: I think you need to know more about the functions $r_i$ to give an answer. Try with some examples to make you an idea.